# Getting value error while enc.transform, where enc is OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False), in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lstm

I have a timeseries dataset name temp which has 4 columns; Date,
Minutes, Issues, Reason no.

in which:

```
temp['REASON NO'].value_counts()
```

shows this output:

```
R13    158
R14    123
R4     101
R7      81
R2      40
R3      35
R5      31
R8      11
R15      9
R12      3
R6       2
R10      2
R9       1
```

I had run this code earlier which ran fine:

```
reason_no = enc.fit_transform(temp['REASON NO'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

But at the end after building model. I wanted to forecast values of Minutes, Issues, Reason no. for next week.

I tried this code:

```
seq_length=7
last_week = df.iloc[-seq_length:, :]
last_reason_no = enc.transform(last_week['REASON NO'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
last_issue = enc.transform(last_week['Issue'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
last_minutes = scaler.transform(last_week['Minutes'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
last_X = np.hstack([last_reason_no, last_issue, last_minutes])
next_X = last_X.reshape(1, last_X.shape[0], last_X.shape[1])
for i in range(7):
    pred = model.predict(next_X)
    pred_minutes = scaler.inverse_transform(pred[:, 2].reshape(-1, 1))[0][0]
    pred_issue = enc.inverse_transform([np.argmax(pred[:, 1])])[0]
    pred_reason_no = enc.inverse_transform([np.argmax(pred[:, 0])])[0]
    print(f'Date: {last_week.iloc[-1, 0]}')
    print(f'Predicted Reason Number: {pred_reason_no}')
    print(f'Predicted Issue: {pred_issue}')
    print(f'Predicted Minutes: {pred_minutes}')
```

But when I run this code, I got an error:

> ValueError
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 last_reason_no = enc.transform(last_week['REASON NO'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
>
> 2 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py
> in _transform(self, X, handle_unknown, force_all_finite,
> warn_on_unknown)
> 172                         " during transform".format(diff, i)
> 173                     )
> --> 174                     raise ValueError(msg)
> 175                 else:
> 176                     if warn_on_unknown:

> ValueError: Found unknown categories ['R5', 'R4'] in column 0 during transform.

Kindly looking for help to learn why I'm getting this error and how to fix it.

Comment: What is your encoder?

Comment: enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't encode categories never seen during transform process:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Something like X_train, X_test = test_train_split(X, ...)
X_train = pd.DataFrame({'REASON NO': ['R13', 'R14', 'R7']})
X_test = pd.DataFrame({'REASON NO': ['R4', 'R7', 'R5']})

enc = OneHotEncoder()
```

Output:

```
>>> enc.fit_transform(X_train).toarray()
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])

>>> enc.transform(X_test)
...
ValueError: Found unknown categories ['R5', 'R4'] in column 0 during transform
```

Comment: But i had encoded my entire dataset earlier.

Comment: However, it's the only way to raise this exception.